# Why do I get a smarty notice "Trying to get property of non-object in ...\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 348"?

Tags: php, smarty, notice

I create my `$smarty` object according to the Smarty manual and I get the following notice:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...\smarty-3.1.32\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 348
```

What does this mean and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Add the code of line #348 to your question.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the very place in the referred line did not really help. See my response below, the error message appears when the object is not initialized by the parent constructor. Calling the constructor, solved the problem.

Comment: How was anyone supposed to guess that? `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` is very generic and easy to accomplish. Seeing the line number that an error is complaining about is the starting point for debugging something properly so without it the best you could have hope for was people wasting their time and guessing but I'm glad you stumbled upon your answer.

Comment: When I saw the error message then I started the investigation with googling for the error message. I found no result so I started to figure it out by myselft. When I got it then I wanted to ease the next person's life and created a self-answered question here. If somebody has the same error message then they can find the answer here. I did know the answer when I asked it, I did not expect anybody to figure it out for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error message appears when you extend the Smarty class but from the new constructor you don't call the parent constructor. Do something like this in your child class:

```
class SmartyExtend extends Smarty {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();  // this is the line that was missing
        $this->setTemplateDir(...);
        $this->setCompileDir(...);
    }
}
```